# How to set the line width to 0.5 pt in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, width, line, r-grid

In `ggplot2`, it is easy to use `element_text` with argument `size=6` to set the font size to 6 pt (For text, size has a unit of pt). However, we cannot use `element_line` with argument `size=0.5` to set the line width to 0.5 pt (For line, size has no unit). So how to solve this problem?

In `grid` package, I meet with the similar question. The code is as following:

```
library(grid)
grid.rect(width=unit(5, "cm"), height=unit(5, "cm"), gp=gpar(lwd=unit(2, "cm")))
```

and the result is:
[image]

Obviously, the line width is not 2 cm comparing with the width or height of the rectangle.

Comment: For the first question, I have got the answer from [https://github.com/yihui/tikzDevice/issues/68](https://github.com/yihui/tikzDevice/issues/68). The correct lwd unit should be 72.27/96 (96 pixels in R is 1 inch, which is 72.27 points in ggplot figure). So I can set the line width to 0.5 pt in ggplot2 by `size=72.27/96*0.5`. However, the second question is still a problem.

Answer (score 1):

a lwd unit is obviously 1/96 of an inch for the pdf device, and it extends symmetrically on either side of the line

```
grid.newpage()
grid.rect(width=unit(1, "cm")+unit(1,"mm"), 
          height=unit(1, "cm")+unit(1,"mm"), 
          gp=gpar(lwd=96/2.54, alpha=0.5, linejoin="mitre",linejoin=1))
```

[image]

However, in windows system, the result is:

[image]

Comment: Is it different in windows system with in Mac system?

Comment: `?par` mentions that the interpretation of lwd is device-specific, so you may have better luck with a pdf device than this interactive device.