# How is the line width (size) defined in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

The line width (`size`) aesthetics in `ggplot2` seems to print approximately 2.13 pt wider lines to a pdf (the experiment was done in Adobe Illustrator with a Mac):

```
library(ggplot2)

dt <- data.frame(id = rep(letters[1:5], each = 3), x = rep(seq(1:3), 5), y = rep(seq(1:5), each = 3), s = rep(c(0.05, 0.1, 0.5, 1, 72.27/96*0.5), each = 3))

lns <- split(dt, dt$id)

ggplot() + geom_line(data = lns[[1]], aes(x = x, y = y), size = unique(lns[[1]]$s)) + 
  geom_text(data = lns[[1]], y = unique(lns[[1]]$y), x = 3.5, label = paste("Width in ggplot =", unique(lns[[1]]$s))) + 
  geom_line(data = lns[[2]], aes(x = x, y = y), size = unique(lns[[2]]$s)) + 
  geom_text(data = lns[[2]], y = unique(lns[[2]]$y), x = 3.5, label = paste("Width in ggplot =", unique(lns[[2]]$s))) + 
  geom_line(data = lns[[3]], aes(x = x, y = y), size = unique(lns[[3]]$s)) + 
  geom_text(data = lns[[3]], y = unique(lns[[3]]$y), x = 3.5, label = paste("Width in ggplot =", unique(lns[[3]]$s))) + 
  geom_line(data = lns[[4]], aes(x = x, y = y), size = unique(lns[[4]]$s)) + 
  geom_text(data = lns[[4]], y = unique(lns[[4]]$y), x = 3.5, label = paste("Width in ggplot =", unique(lns[[4]]$s))) + 
  geom_line(data = lns[[5]], aes(x = x, y = y), size = unique(lns[[5]]$s)) + 
  geom_text(data = lns[[5]], y = unique(lns[[5]]$y), x = 3.5, label = paste("Width in ggplot =", unique(lns[[5]]$s))) + 
  xlim(1,4) + theme_void()

ggsave("linetest.pdf", width = 8, height = 2)

# Device size does not affect line width:
ggsave("linetest2.pdf", width = 10, height = 6)
```

[image]

I read that [one should multiply the line width by 72.27/96 to get a line width in pt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35135632/how-to-set-the-line-width-to-0-5-pt-in-ggplot2), but the experiment above gives me a line width of 0.8 pt, when I try to get 0.5 pt.

[As @Pascal points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36478278/ggsave-does-not-constrain-line-width), the [line width does not seem to follow the pt to mm conversion that works for fonts and was defined by @hadley in one of the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17311917/ggplot2-the-unit-of-size). I.e. the line width does not appear to be defined by "the magic number" 1/0.352777778.

What is the equation behind line width for ggplot2?

Comment: I think the real question is in what units the grid package measures line width. ggplot2 definitely uses size*.pt, see line 189 here: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/R/geom-path.r

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You had all the pieces in your post already. First, ggplot2 multiplies the `size` setting by `ggplot2::.pt`, which is defined as 72.27/25.4 = 2.845276 (line 165 in [geom-.r](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/b05c6c1f61a52311809ffda775eb258b07518dab/R/geom-.r)):

```
> ggplot2::.pt
[1] 2.845276
```

Then, as you state, you need to multiply the resulting value by 72.27/96 to convert from R pixels to points. Thus the conversion factor is:

```
> ggplot2::.pt*72.27/96
[1] 2.141959
```

As you can see, ggplot2 size = 1 corresponds to approximately 2.14pt, and similarly 0.8 pt corresponds to 0.8/2.141959 = 0.3734899 in ggplot2 size units.